# can we define env variable in the helm charts only if secrets are provisioned?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

we have below env variable in the helm hooks yaml file.

```
env:
   - name:PASSWORD
     value: {{ .Values.cmpassword | default "User@1234" | quote }}
```

i need to check if a particular secrets are created already and then password should take values from secrets like

```
{ if kubectl  get secret passwdsecret1 -o yaml | grep password }}
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: cmpasswdsecret
              key:  password
          
{{else}}
          value: {{ .Values.global.cmpassword | default "User@1234" | quote }}
{{end}}
```

is it possible to check whether secrets are created. if the secrets are availbale derive the value from it, or take the values from value file.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitnami Helm charts](https://github.com/bitnami/charts) generally address this by making the related Secret name a configuration option.  I'd suggest this as a useful general approach here, since you'll get a consistent deployment regardless of what's actually in the cluster.  If the administrator says the secret is supposed to exist, but it doesn't, the Pods will fail to start up; that's probably a better outcome than falling back to an insecure default.

The `values.yaml` configuration for this could look like

```yaml
# existingSecret, if set, has the name of a Secret to use for
# credentials.  This must contain a key `password`.
# existingSecret:

# cmpassword specifies the password.  Ignored if `existingSecret`
# is provided.
cmpassword: User@1234
```

Then in your actual template code you can generate the `secretKeyRef` if `existingSecret` is specified, or fall back to the `cmpassword` if not.

```yaml
env:
  - name: PASSWORD
{{- with .Values.existingSecret }}
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: {{ . }}
        key: password
{{- else }}
    value: {{ .Values.cmpassword | required "either existingSecret or cmpassword is required" | quote }}
{{- end }}
```